# Aldryn Forms setup: how to add add recipients

Tags: divio

I try to use Aldryn forms on the Aldryn platform.

In one form, a setup for recepients is possible.
In another form the recipients part are missing.

What could be the difference between both forms?

How do I add recipients to a form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how to do it:

One has to choose a theme: default.
Then click:
+ Add another New email notification.
[screenprint initial settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgX9a.png)

Then one has to save first and reopen the form settings.
Now there is a section "Recipients" and "Email".
Here you can enter the addresses.
[screenprint reopened after save](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhu4e.png)

Create and "advanced form" to enter custom email addresses, or one has to choose from the cms-user list.